# Image in Imageview only androidstudio no in emulator or phone

Tags: java, android, image, android-studio, android-studio-2.2

I have a problmem with images.

After I ubdate androidstudio on 2.2.0 all imageview which build have image only in androidstudio if i editing xml file. but if start app in genymotion or launch apk in phone image not show.

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_height="40sp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/additem_button"
    android:id="@+id/imageView36"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_width="51sp"
    android:layout_gravity="right" />
</FrameLayout>
```

I have all images in ldpi,mdpi,hdpi,xhdpi,xxhdpi,xxxhdpi, but I launch app only xxhdpi phones and run without new imageviews... please How resolve thise problem..Thanks..

Comment: Why dont you use android:background or android:src instead of srcCompat?

Comment: uf, i dont know, on this put andoridstudio automatically. I going to try put image via simple src...

Comment: now thise error if i generated apk

Comment: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageRelease'.
> java.io.IOException: Failed to create '....\app-release.apk'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try this and run good.

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_height="40sp"
    android:src="@drawable/additem_button"
    android:id="@+id/imageView36"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_width="51sp"
    android:layout_gravity="right" />
```